# AngularJS with node-webkit

Tags: angularjs, node-webkit

I am right now evaluating node-webkit as a possible solution for building desktop application with web technologies and have a slight issue.  The application is using AngularJS and the issue I am running into is that is does not seem to be properly loading my html template files.

My test application has this config:

```
nucleusApps.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/style', {
      templateUrl: '/templates/core/style.html',
      controller: nucleusApps.controllers.Style
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/style'});
}]);
```

The issue is that I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to load resource     file://templates/core/style.html
```

I have tried a number of different format for the templateUrl including:

```
./templates/core/style.html
file://template/core/style.html
```

But I keep getting this error.  Also my directory structure is:

```
-index.html
-package.json
-css
  -file.css
  -etc...
-templates
  -core
    style.html
-etc...
```

This is what is being zipped up.

Do you know why I might be getting this error?

**- UPDATE -**

Not sure what is going on here but just updated my code (the web version I am building) and everything is working fine now. Must have been something weird in the older code

Comment: Not sure what is going on here but just updated my code (the web version I am building) and everything is working fine now.  Must have been something weird in the older code

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to use html5mode, but therein lies the problem. [$locationProvider,](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Comment: Removing that fixing the fail to load resource (along with making the path ./templates/corestyle.html) however I am not getting an error that is just repeating over and over of : 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: without your other code, i would guess that you are 1) calling scope.$apply when you shouldn't be or 2) changing something that angular thinks you shouldn't be like an internal angular construct (something like angular.$$foo).

Comment: why would it work fine in the chrome browser but not with node-webkit (which uses chromium)?

Comment: hmm good question, you might want to research angularjs googlegroup, i  seem to recall there issues with partials - particularly with chrome. Sorry, i don't have node-webkit exp.